# Data classes for Firebase and Firebase Admin

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was writing a project using firebase firestore, and I made some data classes, so that I could access the data in a better way. The problem I'm facing is that the firestore classes are not compatible with the admin ones (and vice versa I think).
Here is the code:

```js
export class User {
    email: string;
    displayName?: string;
    tokens: DocumentReference<Token>[];
    admin: boolean = false;

    constructor({
        email,
        displayName,
        admin,
        tokens,
    }: {
        email: string;
        displayName?: string;
        admin?: boolean;
        tokens?: DocumentReference<Token>[];
    }) {
        this.email = email;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.tokens = tokens ?? [];
        this.admin = admin ?? false;
    }

    static collectionName = 'users';
    static converter: FirestoreDataConverter<User> = {
        toFirestore: (user: User) => {
            return { ...user };
        },
        fromFirestore: (snapshot): User => {
            const data = snapshot.data();
            return new User({
                email: data.email,
                displayName: data.displayName,
                tokens: data.tokens ?? [],
                admin: data.admin,
            });
        },
    };
}

export class Token {
    device?: number;
    devices: number;
    expiration?: Timestamp;
    owner: DocumentReference<User>;
    project: DocumentReference<Project>;
    tier: number;

    constructor({
        owner,
        project,
        device,
        devices,
        expiration,
        tier,
    }: {
        owner: DocumentReference<User>;
        project: DocumentReference<Project>;
        device?: number;
        devices: number;
        expiration?: Timestamp;
        tier: number;
    }) {
        this.owner = owner;
        this.project = project;
        this.device = device;
        this.devices = devices;
        this.expiration = expiration;
        this.tier = tier;
    }

    static collectionName = 'tokens';
    static converter = {
        toFirestore: (token: Token) => {
            return { ...token };
        },
        fromFirestore: (
            snapshot: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData, DocumentData>,
        ): Token => {
            const data = snapshot.data();
            console.log(data);
            return new Token({
                device: data.device,
                devices: data.devices,
                expiration: data.expiration,
                owner: data.owner,
                project: data.project,
                tier: data.tier,
            });
        },
    };
}

export class Project {
    name: string;
    version?: string;
    tokens: DocumentReference<Token>[];
    tiers: number;

    constructor({
        name,
        version,
        tokens,
        tiers,
    }: {
        name: string;
        version?: string;
        tokens?: DocumentReference<Token>[];
        tiers: number;
    }) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
        this.tokens = tokens ?? [];
        this.tiers = tiers;
    }

    static collectionName = 'projects';
    static converter: FirestoreDataConverter<Project> = {
        toFirestore: (project: Project) => {
            return { ...project };
        },
        fromFirestore: (snapshot): Project => {
            const data = snapshot.data();
            return new Project({
                name: data.name,
                version: data.version,
                tokens: data.tokens ?? [],
                tiers: data.tiers,
            });
        },
    };
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to write these classes once, instead of writing one version for the normal and one for the admin one.

Comment: The objects between web and admin are definitely not the same and don't behave exactly the same.  If you want to share query code, you will need some sort of wrapper around each that makes them look and behave the same from the perspective of the calling code.  This is not trivial.